# How to export the start date and time in MS Project?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, ms-project

I am working with Progress 4gl(11.7) version where I came across a scenario where We are doing Job/task export from application to MS project. Everything is working fine but we have a problem in Percentage Complete where if the job/task duration is 1.5 days after exporting to MS Project its calculating 2 days which is changing the Percent Complete automatically.
So I figured may be as we are exporting only date not time, calculation is also happening in Dates.

Now I tried to export the time as well in the start and end date.
This is what I have tried

```
DEF VAR objPrj       AS COM-HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR objActivePrj AS COM-HANDLE NO-UNDO.

CREATE "MSProject.Application" objPrj. /*Created a project object*/
objActivePrj = objPrj:ActiveProject(). /*Activated the project*/

objActiveTask = objActivePrj:Tasks:ADD("", vTaskId).  /*Add the Task*/
objActiveTask = objActivePrj:Tasks:Item(vTaskId).  /*Add the Task ID*/
objActiveTask:START  = DATETIME("05-30-2020 03:30 pm"). /*Added hardcoded date and time*/
```

which is working perfectly fine I am able to export this time in the MS Project.

Now if I do the similar assignment something like

```
objActiveTask:START  = DATETIME(STRING(02/24/24,"99-99-9999") + " " +  STRING(15:00, "HH:MM:SS"))
```

Where STRING(02/24/24,"99-99-9999") will be replaced by date variable and STRING(15:00, "HH:MM:SS") will be replaced by time variable.

The time and date is exporting but its exporting wrong like 02/29/2024 00:00 in MS project.

What could we do to export the time and the date correctly? If you have worked on any kind MS project Exporting Program please guide me. Thank you very much.

Comment: "Something like" is unnecessarily ambiguous. You are doing something wrong, so show exactly what you are doing that is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In your hard-coded case you have:

```
objActiveTask:START = DATETIME("05-30-2020 03:30 pm").
```

You say that that works, so I will trust that it does.

Your "something like" case that doesn't work looks like this:

```
objActiveTask:START = DATETIME(STRING(02/24/24,"99-99-9999") + " " +  STRING(15:00, "HH:MM:SS")).
```

Which does not compile (so it is a mystery how you get a *wrong* export - you should get nothing at all...). The main problem that I see *in the code that you have shared* is that 15:00 is not a valid constant. Time values are integer seconds since midnight. So "15:00" should be (( 15 * 3600 ) + ( 0 * 60 ) + 0 )

thus the code should be:

objActiveTask:START = DATETIME(STRING(02/24/24,"99-99-9999") + " " +  STRING(15 * 3600 + 0 * 60 + 0, "HH:MM:SS")).

That isn't "wrong" but it would be cleaner to skip all of the string building and just use the date & time directly. DATETIME() supports DATETIME( date, milliseconds ) so a cleaner statement would be:

```
DATETIME( 02/24/24, ( 15 * 3600 + 0 * 60 + 0)  * 1000 )
```

or, perhaps:

objActiveTask:START = DATETIME( TODAY, TIME * 1000 ).

or, even:

```
objActiveTask:START = NOW.
```

Comment: The last `)` belongs to the `DATETIME` function

Comment: You're right. I somehow got an extra one when I copied it to test it :( I'll edit my answer.

Comment: 15 * 3600 + 0 * 60 + 0 is very unABL, I think you meant to use something like:

def var dt as datetime no-undo.

assign 
   dt = today
   dt = add-interval( dt, 15, 'hours' )
   dt = add-interval( dt, 0, 'minutes' )
   dt = add-interval( dt, 0, 'seconds' )
   . 
      
message dt view-as alert-box.

Comment: Sure, I was trying to keep my changes within the footprint of the provided sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you don't want to use this variant of the [DATETIME](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/abl-reference/page/DATETIME-function.html?labelkey=product_openedge_128) function?

```
DATETIME ( month , day , year , hours , minutes 
       [ , seconds[ , milliseconds]] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `STRING(15:00, "HH:MM:SS")` with `"15:00"`.

See example in [ABL Dojo](https://abldojo.services.progress.com/?shareId=65d7766120add51d93a67afc).